# VBA Replace() Function with Multiple Strings in Same Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro send multiple emails that are customized based on the data required.

For example:

```
Subject: <name>, Thank you for visiting <store>
```

At the moment, I can only pull , but I have no idea how to also add  so 'Content' will both of them.

```
Content = Replace(msg.Subject, "<name>", first_name + " " + last_Name)
          Replace(msg.Subject, "<store>", store_name)
```

^ essentially I want to combine both of these so the macro will pull both.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show us what you  tried. Stackoerflow it is not a free developing source, you should show your effort and where you got stacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple steps:

```
Content = Replace(msg.Subject, "<name>", first_name + " " + last_Name)
Content = Replace(Content, "<store>", store_name)
```

Or you could nest your Replace statements:

```
Content = Replace(Replace(msg.Subject, "<name>", first_name + " " + last_Name), "<store>", store_name)
```

If you ended up with a large number of tokens to replace (or an ever growing dynamic number of them) then you could get fancy and iterate through the string to identify tokens and swap them out inside the loop, but that would be overkill here.

Comment: The first option doesn't work as the second content supercedes the first one (this was the first thing I tried). But the nesting works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: The first and second are functionally identical. Note that I put `Content` variable inside of the second `Replace` to ensure both replaces happen on the original string. The first is much easier to read and if you get more than a few tokens to replace would be the more maintainable route. Glad to hear the second is working for you :)